# How to change keyboard layout on personalize page?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-layout

I just installed Windows 8 on my machine. When I started it, personalization screen was shown and I was asked to enter the PC name.

The problem is that none of the existing keyboard layouts are working. I tried with all (2 armenian and 1 r russian), but am getting this error message:

> **This keyboard layout can't be used to enter a name for this PC. Try using a different keyboard.**

Comment: is there no onscreen keyboard option ?

Comment: There is, but I am getting same error when typing name from it.

Comment: shutdown your PC, unplug your keyboard, boot up and type in your name. Then shutdown and plug in your keyboard and change the setting?

Comment: Same message with unplaged keyboard @Taylor Gibb.

Comment: not really sure then, I only have en-US keyboards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem solved.
I formatted and installed it again, this time setting as English (language, time settings) and it worked.
Thanks to Microsoft for this issue, they are doing their best to make difficulties to users as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Microsoft Fixit** to resolve the issue.

There is a whole Knowledge Base for it in Microsoft(As mentioned with Win 7 but it works for win 8)

The Link:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927824

Try Login into Safe mode.. if possible

Check also if you are using the  ISO with  Correct Language options

AS you are using PS/2 K/B you need to find an USB K/b available uninstall the K/B from Device Manager with an alternate USB K/B attached.Then scan for Hardware changes it will automatically detect your PS/2 K/B and you can give this USB K/B back from where you bought it (be it from a friend..)

It is a BUG in Windows 8 RTM edition that is causing the issue as per the discussion at MSDN also 
they briefed 
he power management for PS/2 devices has been change for Win8 and hence the bug

The whole detail about the discussion can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wdk/thread/a65356b2-5b08-4841-b24c-bb223e161102/)

Comment: I am not using USB keyboard

Comment: Then which keyboard are you PS2?

Comment: And also I cannot log in. This is first run, I even didn't add Live ID yet.

Comment: Yes, it's PS2 keyboard

Comment: hey Samvel I have updated my answer...Check.

Comment: My K/B is working, I can type text, but I am getting error when clicking next, also I can go to control panel only from Win7 (I have both installed), but not sure uninstalling drivers from Win7 will help Win8. On Win7 it is working as expected.

Comment: Try to open On screen keyboard and then type with the mouse. For this hit the `Shift` key for 5 times, and now open the **Ease of access center** and open the Onscreen K/B from there.

Comment: As you can read from comments under question, I did that, and got same error message.

Comment: I will reinstall Windows 8, but this time with english settings. Hope that will help.

Comment: I think it should help... if you still face the issue please update so that we can try for better solution....Check the Correct ISO for Win 8

Comment: Just Note. Keyboard was working for Developer Preview and Consumer Preview versions.

Comment: Try to install it with English version and with default option like US K/B layout and then you can change the setting nside the Windows later.